# How to input n strings in C (n is entered by the user) without allocating n spaces?

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, scanf

I was trying to solve a problem whose input format is like this-

```
n       // no. of strings
first string
second string
.....
nth string    // n strings to be input separated by newlines
```

For each string input, some modifications have to be done on it and the modified string is to be output.

Instead of allocating separate space for each of the n strings using malloc, I was trying this approach:-

```
char str[MAX_SIZE];
scanf("%d",&no_of_testcases);

    while(no_of_testcases -- ){

     scanf("%[^\n]s",str);

    /* some processing on the input string*/
    /* printing the modified string */

    }
```

Can't the same space (str) be used to store user input string multiple times in each iteration?? The given code wasn't behaving/taking the input the way I wanted to have.

Comment: c or c++? choose. Looks like C to me.

Comment: The problem is `%[^\n]` **`s`**. That `s` doesn't belong there. Also, you want to eat the whitespace after the integer: `scanf("%d ", ...)`

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",str);` --> `scanf("%[^\n]",str);`. The trailing `s` is not part of the scanset directive.

Comment: *What* error? Build error? Run-time error or crash? Wrong output? Please elaborate! And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: *My code was giving error* - don't you think you need to mention the error?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala-- `scanf("%d ", ...)`. That trailing whitespace will cause `scanf()` to block, waiting for a non-whitespace input. OP maybe should do: `scanf("%[^\n]s",str);` --> `scanf(" %[^\n]",str);` (leading whitespace added to format string).

Comment: @DavidBowling corrected, still the problem is there

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya not an error actually, it is not taking the input as desired

Comment: @KrishnaBagaria-- you corrections are wrong. From the current edit, change: `scanf("%d ",&no_of_testcases);` --> `scanf("%d",&no_of_testcases);`, and change `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` --> `scanf(" %[^\n]",str);`. Your whitespace is in the wrong place.

Comment: Also, why not just use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` for this?

Comment: @DavidBowlingcorrected now and it is working :). I know about fgets() and sscanf(), just trying to understand scanf() clearly, Also still I didnt get why this solution worked

Comment: @KrishnaBagaria-- the first call to `scanf()` left a `\n` character in the input stream (which is a whitespace character). The second call to `scanf()` was picking this up, because `%[]` does not ignore whitespace characters. Adding the whitespace to the beginning tells `scanf()` to skip over zero or more whitespace characters before the next directive.

Comment: @DavidBowling though it is running perfectly fine on my compiler, but it is showing some absurd output @ @ @ @ @......on the online codind judge.Please help

Comment: Avoid edits that change the nature of the post.  If needed _append_ additional data.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to use the same buffer to read lines one at a time as long as you process the data read into the buffer completely before proceeding to the next line, many programs do just that.

Note however that you should protect against potential buffer overflow by telling `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to store into the buffer:

```
char str[1024];
int no_of_testcases;

if (scanf("%d", &no_of_testcases) == 1) {
    while (no_of_testcases-- > 0) {
        if (scanf(" %1023[^\n]", str) != 1) {
            /* conversion failure, most probably premature end of file */
            break;
        }
        /* some processing on the input string */
        /* printing the modified string */
    }
}
```

Skipping the pending white-space before the input string is a good way to consume the newlines, but has the side effect of skipping initial white space on the input lines and also ignoring empty lines, which may or may not be useful.

If more precise parsing is required, you could use `fgets()`.